# .click() on image does not work as expected

Tags: jquery, click, image

I am attempting to alert some text when an image is clicked.

javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".delRow").click('function() {
        alert("hello!");
    });
});
```

html code:

```
<img src="../images/delete.png" alt="delete" class="delRow"></img>
```

This code seems straight forward; however, it is not working as expected.  Are images handled differently when using .click?

-Thanks,
  Rich

Comment: Is that `'` before `function() {` a typo in the question or is it in your code?

Comment: What is it doing / not doing?  I notice that you have an open quote mark in `.click('function()...`. Is that a typo in your post, or is it in your code?

Comment: It is a typo  I changed the code to:  
  
     $(".delRow").click(function() {
         alert("hello!");
     });  
  
But, it still is not working as expected.  I have multiple images with their classes the same, but I do not think that would cause the issue.

Comment: There was code before my .click which caused this issue :-)  
I forgot javascript works from top to bottom.  The code that executed before the issue worked; but the code below the error did not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".delRow").click(function() {
        alert("hello!");
    });
});
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/frQSm/)

Comment: That code works as expected for a button.  I am still having the issue with my image.

Comment: glad you found the answer @dottedquad please either post your solution and accept it as an answer or accept one of the answers given here

Answer (score 2):

You have extra ' at click.(function(){

It should be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".delRow").click(function() {
        alert("hello!");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".delRow").click(function() {
        alert("hello!");
    });
});
```

Remove the " `'` " before the second `function`